# IE8 Website Display Issues - Virtual Desktop

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am after some advice...

I have recently created a website, Wordpress based using HTML5, CSS etc. Upon testing the site it displays fine in all modern browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome etc). I am using a Mac so tested in IE via Virtual Box and free online browser rendering services, all seem to display correctly even IE8! However... A friend who will also being using the site via a virtual desktop (not Virtual Box) has tested in IE8 and the site does not display correctly, it seems like the CSS is not being loaded... There is no styling.

I have added HTML Shiv etc to combat the HTML5 issues but this doesn't seem to fix the issue. It seems odd it displays correctly in IE8 via Virtual Box but not in IE8 via others, does anyone know anything I could try? Could Windows XP or 98 render differently? Would really appreciate some advice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the compatibility IE use. In IE 8 if this setting is on the engine it use is from older versions of IE. So if your site looks good in IE you can add a meta tag to force the user IE to view the site with the compatibility turned off.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use `IE8` you will need to work for it! `IE8` does not support `media queries` and wordpress uses them a ton. There are way's around it,
Google search "using media queries with IE8" and you will find tons of work arounds.